# Directions on porting my angular 2 app to electron

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, electron

are there any newer tutorials on porting my already completed angular2 app with plenty of routers components and services? I have been working on this for literally 20 hours straight with out getting anywhere. Please lend me a hand. The older tutrorials have either deprecated ways or does not incorporate routers. I tried using the popular tutorials from 
https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/
and 
http://tphangout.com/angular-2-desktop-apps-with-electron/

these did not help me though. Any other ideas?

Comment: What specific errors or problems are you running into?

Comment: Well specifically I just can't get more than one component to work. My app was ran by many routers, but now that I am merging it to Electron I cannot figure out how to get it to work

Comment: Your description still isn't very specific (e.g. an error message and stack trace would be helpful). Do your routers use HTML5 push state (I think that's the default in ng2)? That could be causing problems, so try switching them to use old-school #hash URLs strategy. Also using webpack in Electron usually requires a special electron target to work so that all your native node.js and electron api requires don't get mangled by webpack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to below  https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/master/default_app

`electron.js`

```
const electron = require('electron-prebuilt'),
  proc = require('child_process'),
  child = proc.spawn(electron, ['.']
```

`main.js` - https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/default_app/main.js

```
const electron = require("electron"),
app = electron.app;
app.on("ready", function(){
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    autoHideMenuBar: false,
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
  });
 mainWindow.loadURL('file://'+__dirname+'/index.html'););
}
```

You can also host nodejs server using https://github.com/theallmightyjohnmanning/electron-express

Tutorial:
http://electron.rocks/electron-angular-creating-sample-application/

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused. I have the main.js,  but what does the electron.js do? And are you saying that I need nodejs server to run routers

Comment: electron.js load electron-prebuilt. and creating main process. and main.js is the config & code of main process. main process will open renderer process(BrowserWindow) https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md